# Converting SQL number into a time, to perform date comparisons

Tags: sql, datetime, comparison, db2, ibm-midrange

I am struggling with an SQL time comparison on two fields that have been set up as integers, rather than time stamps.

I have some performance metrics in a database that the developer originally set up as int(8). The database contains the start and end times of a transaction. For example

Some sample data may be

```
id | start_time | end_time
---------------------------
1  |      85958 | 90001
```

If I simply subtracted the two values, I would get 4043 seconds, when the transaction time is only 3. I am struggling however to convert the values into a time format that allows me to perform date comparisons.

I am unable to do this calculation within the application, because there are 100's of rows in the database per day, and I am trying to calculate the average and max times for the transactions.

EDIT:

To clarify

The times are in seconds
85958 represent 8:59:58 90001 represents 9:00:01

To make things worse, 1 minute past midnight 0:01:00 would be represented as 100.

Comment: I believe those are milliseconds, perhaps elapsed from initiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the answers already described are all valid, but unfortunately the iSeries seems to quibble over different functions and so I had to tailor the answers given to get it to work.

The final solution I got was

`select
TIME(SUBSTR(DIGITS(END_TIME),1,2) CONCAT ':' CONCAT SUBSTR(DIGITS(END_TIME),3,2) CONCAT ':' CONCAT SUBSTR(DIGITS(END_TIME),5,2)) - TIME(SUBSTR(DIGITS(START_TIME),1,2) CONCAT ':' CONCAT SUBSTR(DIGITS(START_TIME),3,2) CONCAT ':' CONCAT SUBSTR(DIGITS(START_TIME),5,2))
from table1;`

Thanks for all the quick and detailed responses

Comment: What is shown would not function for the alluded DDL [column attributes] for the END_TIME and START_TIME, apparently as either INT(8) or INTEGER; i.e. the DIGITS casting scalar of an INTEGER is a 10-digit string, and of a BIGINT is a 19-digit string. Those columns would need to be defined as something like DEC(6) or NUMERIC(6). Also, there are much simpler expressions for effecting the same, if even using TIME data could be considered appropriate for the alluded purpose -- which would be a hard sell; e.g. `time('00010101' concat digits(start_time ))`

Answer (score 3):

I tested this in MySQL but I'm sure the technique can be adapted to work in DB2:

```
SELECT
    (end_time DIV 10000) * 3600 +
    ((end_time DIV 100) % 100) * 60 +
    end_time % 100 -
    (start_time DIV 10000) * 3600 -
    ((start_time DIV 100) % 100) * 60 -
    start_time % 100
FROM table1
```

Result:

```
3
```

The way it works is to use integer division and the modulo operation to extract the HH MM and SS parts of each timestamp and convert each part into seconds. The seconds are then added together to form a total number of seconds since midnight for each timestamp. The difference between these two gives the transaction time.

Note that this won't work if the transaction starts before midnight and finishes after midnight. You may need to consider if the day has changed and correct for this. If you don't have the day stored in your database then you can look for negative transation times and add 24 hours to make them positive and this should give the correct result (as long as transactions don't exceed one day in length, but I guess that this is unlikely in practice).

My attempt at writing this for DB2 (not tested):

```
SELECT
    (end_time / 10000) * 3600 +
    MOD(end_time / 100, 100) * 60 +
    MOD(end_time, 100) -
    (start_time / 10000) * 3600 -
    MOD(start_time / 100, 100) * 60 -
    MOD(start_time, 100)
FROM table1
```

Comment: This sounds really promising. Pretty sure this will work. Thank you! I will feedback when I have a chance to run the code.

Comment: @Codemwnci: From Googling it seems that DB2 does integer division by default when you write `a / b`, as opposed to MySQL where `a / b` does floating point division. This is why I used `DIV` instead of `/` in MySQL, but you probably need to use `/` on DB2. Sorry for the vagueness but I don't have DB2 installed so I can't test it to be sure.

Comment: @Codemwnci: I've done some more Googling and it seems that instead of `x % y` you need to use the `MOD(x, y)` function.

Comment: @Codemwnci: I've updated my post with my best guess as to how this would work in DB2, but it is not tested. If it doesn't work and you can't figure out why yourself then let me know what incorrect result or error you get.

Comment: I tried this solution, but on the iSeries I was unable to get it to work and couldn't get to the bottom of it. So, I ended up using the digits and time functions.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using DB2 for LUW, you can do this using a few functions:

- DIGITS() – gives you a zero-padded character string of your integer
- TRANSLATE() - reformat the character string
- MIDNIGHT_SECONDS - return the number of seconds since midnight for a time.

This will work in cases were the value 100 = '00:01:00'.

Example:

```
select
   id,
   MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TRANSLATE('EF:GH:IJ',DIGITS(end_time),'ABCDEFGHIJ')) -
      MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TRANSLATE('EF:GH:IJ',DIGITS(start_time),'ABCDEFGHIJ')) as runtime
from
   your_table;
```

The above expression will not work if start_time > end_time (i.e., start_time is before midnight, but end_time is after midnight).

Of course, the real problem here is using an INT to store a TIME.  It would be better to just fix your data model so it uses TIME (or better, a TIMESTAMP).

Comment: I tried this solution, but unfortunately I am using iSeries DB2, and the translate function failed. I instead had to use substring and concatenation to produce the translation, and then the solution worked.

Comment: Yes, tagging a post with "db2" is usually not sufficient.  You need to say what platform you're running on, as there are some differences between DB2 LUW, DB2 on zSeries and DB2 on iSeries.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need to convert? Perhaps the number represents milliseconds, so the difference would be ~4 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the values are actually meant to be 08:59:58 and 09:00:01 in hours:minutes:seconds by guessing the end difference is 3

but these are all guesses you need to ask others in your company what they are - as someone else must have used these even if the original coder had left